# AIR for Android. тормозит приложение

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-3, air, adobe-air

Здравствуйте. Я делал простую игру в Adobe Flash CS6, писал на ActionScript 3.0. для AIR for Android. При отладке приложения на компьютере, все идет замечательно. Но на телефоне игра начинает жутко тормозить. Графики в ней, как таковой, нет. Кода в ней тоже немного, так что я подумал, что инлайн не потребуется.
При публикации в консоле два раза возникает сообщение: "Предупреждение. Нет библиотек, связанных в качестве общих библиотек времени выполнения (Runtime shared library, RSL), так как в настройках публикации выбрано: AIR 3.4 for Android". 
Скажите пожалуйста: может ли проблема заключаться в отсутствии данных библиотек? И если - да, то как ее исправить?

Comment: в подобных случаях говорят, что ошибка в 17 строке в втором файле слева.

По факту - а кто его знает, почему оно тормозит. Причин сотни

- старый андроид, мало памяти.
- в коде есть длинные циклы.

Comment: А вы на телефон ставите финальную сборку или отладочную? Отладочные сборки на девайсах о-о-очень долго запускаются и работают медленнее финальных. Если дело не в этом, то советую посмотреть, что ваше приложение пишет в лог на девайсе.

Answer (score 1):

Давно делал игру на движке flixel. Так вот решил запустить ее на мобильнике. Оказалось, что большие BitmapData (на весь экран) и постоянные copyPixel в нее в enterFrame, убивают весь фпс на телефонах, притом, что на десктопах все наоборот, быстро.

Comment: Внезапно, блиттинг на мобилах портит производительность? Может, там было перевыделение памяти под битмапы помимо всего прочего?

Comment: Не могу точно сказать, было сто лет назад

Answer (score 1):

Рендер через обычный Stage обречен на низкую производительность на мобильных платформах так как не рационально использует железо устройства. Векторная графика дополнительно его грузит. Вывести таким способом даже небольшое количество графики очень проблематично. Остерегайтесь векторной графики, крупных битмапов, прозрачности, не используйте анимацию через flash (вместо этого используйте программную анимацию и спрайтшиты или спрайт листы). Рендер на мобильные платформы во Flash следует делать через Stage3D. Чтобы быстро адаптировать вашу разработку под Stage3D можете попробовать использовать фреймверк Starling. Почти наверняка проблема в этом.